# Building a wpf graph. What is the recommended approach for creating a canvas dot

Tags: wpf

I am trying to build my own graph control using wpf (c#).
I am using a canvas.
The question is very basic, How should I draw a point on the graph (Canvas):

1. as a single dot.
2. as a circle with a radius of 1.
3. as a rectangle with a length of 1.
4. another method

What is the recommended approach and why ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), all of the children are explicitly positioned. To draw simple shapes, add a [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to the Canvas.

Example from code:

```
var myRectangle = new Rectangle
{
    Width = 200,
    Height = 50,
    Fill = Brushes.Black
};

Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, 100);

myCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle);
```

Example from XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas">
    <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="100"
               Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Black" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and help, But I am looking at understanding how to draw a point. Should I draw a dot a rectangle or a circle. I would like to understand what is the best way to do it.

Comment: If you want to draw a point, use the exact same code, but replace the `Rectangle` with an `Ellipse` and set the `Width` and `Height` to 1

Comment: Thanks again, As you have helped with the syntax, There is only one point that is not clear to me, I guess that I might have not clarified my question. What is the preffered method of drawing a point, Rectangle or Elipse? Why is it preferred ? Which method will give me better performance, Will the points scale correctly?

Comment: You can read about WPF Shapes and Basic Drawing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx). The preferred method really depends on whether you want hit testing, layout, input, focus, events, styles, data-binding, resources, and animation etc. or you just want to draw basic shapes. If you just want to draw basic shapes, you could use the [`DrawingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class.